# Win32 API for rename a file in C

Tags: c, winapi, file-rename

If the source directory and the target directory, MoveFile would actually make a copy of the source file into the target file, which means that I will end up seeing two files.

Is that the best way that rename can be achieved?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? `MoveFileEx` with `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` will not give you two files - it calls CopyFile then DeleteFile if the two files are on different volumes.

Comment: I think I've seen instances where MoveFile() will do CopyFile() + DeleteFile(), but the source file is still locked by somebody so it's status will be set to Delete Pending; then when it gets unlocked it magically disappears.  Or maybe I am making this up; can't remember.

Comment: If the program crashes or power is lost, non-atomic Moves (AKA copy-delete) may result in inconsistency.

Comment: See SetFileInformationByHandle  < https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450222/moving-a-file-using-setfileinformationbyhandle>

Comment: Or my gist <https://gist.github.com/ianfun/360bc4074ddefdc3d64697c8b574a132>

Answer (score 11):

The [`MoveFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365239(v=vs.85).aspx) function is indeed what you want. From the documentation:

> The **MoveFile** function will move (rename) either a file or a directory (including its children) either in the same directory or across directories.

If the source and destination locations are both on the same volume, then an atomic rename operation is performed. If they're on different volumes, then a copy/delete operation is done instead (this is the best you can do).

Comment: `MoveFileEx` by default only moves, it will **not copy** unless you pass `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` flag.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Result = rename( oldname , newname );

if (Result)
   // "Error occurred." );
else
   // "File was successfully renamed!";
```

Answer (score 1):

What does your code look like?  I have this:

```
if(MoveFile(_T("c:\\hold\\source"),_T("c:\\hold\\dest")))
{
    printf("succeeded\n");
}else
{
    printf("Error %d\n",GetLastError());
}
```

and it does not leave the source behind.

Comment: This worked after I included: `#include <Windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <Tchar.h>`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the [`MoveFileEx()` API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240.aspx) without specifying the `MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED` to see if that provides the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: Not specifying MOVEFILE_COPY_ALLOWED simply means that cross-volume moves will fail. This is not what the OP wants. The "simulate by Copy/Delete" refers to the fact that cross-volume moves cannot be performed by simply re-writing the disk meta data as is done for same-volume moves.

Comment: @David: I thought the OP was asking for a rename operation that only succeeded if it could be done by changing only the file metadata  instead of a copy/delete rename simulation (I guess the question is a bit unclear to me).

Comment: Well to be fair, the question is posed extremely poorly so, as is so often the case, one can only guess as to what the intent was. Perhaps your interpretation is correct!