# Moving a file using SetFileInformationByHandle

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, file-rename, file-move

I'm trying to move a file using `SetFileInformationByHandle`. This technique has been proposed by Niall Douglas in his CppCon2015 talk "Racing The File System" as a way to atomically move/rename a file. However, I'm struggling to provide correct arguments; it always fails and `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

I've tried this with the following setups, using the Unicode Character Set:

- VS2015U1, running the exe under Windows 10
- VS2015U2, running the exe under Windows Server 2012
- VS2013, running the exe under Windows 7

But the behaviour is the same. I made sure to have access to the test folders and test file.

```
#include <sdkddkver.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    auto const& filepath = L"C:\\remove_tests\\file.txt";
    auto const& destpath = L"C:\\remove_tests\\other.txt";
    // unclear if that's the "root directory"
    auto const& rootdir = L"C:\\remove_tests";

    // handles will be leaked but that should be irrelevant here
    auto const f_handle = CreateFile(filepath,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE | DELETE,
        0,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        NULL);

    if (f_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        auto const err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "failed to create test file: " << err;
        return err;
    }

    auto const parent_dir_handle = CreateFile(rootdir,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
        NULL);

    if (parent_dir_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        auto const err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "failed to get handle to parent directory: " << err;
        return err;
    }

    auto const destpath_bytes_with_null = sizeof(destpath);
    // unclear if we need to subtract the one wchar_t of FileNameLength:
    auto const struct_size = sizeof(FILE_RENAME_INFO) + destpath_bytes_with_null;
    auto const buf = std::make_unique<char[]>(struct_size);

    auto const fri = reinterpret_cast<FILE_RENAME_INFO*>(buf.get());
    fri->ReplaceIfExists =  TRUE; // as described by Niall Douglas
    fri->RootDirectory = parent_dir_handle;
    // with or without null terminator?
    fri->FileNameLength = destpath_bytes_with_null;
    std::memcpy(fri->FileName, destpath, destpath_bytes_with_null);

    BOOL res = SetFileInformationByHandle(f_handle, FileRenameInfo,
                                          fri, struct_size);
    if (!res)
    {
        auto const err = GetLastError();
        std::cerr << "failed to rename file: " << err;
        return err;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "success";
}
```

In particular, my questions are:

- What is the "root directory" as required by `FILE_RENAME_INFO`?
- Which permissions are required for the handles?
- What's the underlying problem of the `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` produced by `SetFileInformationByHandle`?

Comment: Same problem as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217150/deleting-a-file-based-on-disk-id).

Comment: @HansPassant Well I had no trouble using `SetFileInformationByHandle` to *delete* files. However I'm having trouble using it to *move* files. Also, I'm not using `OpenFileById`. Could you please be a bit more specific as to what the similarity is between the issue I have and the questions/answers you've linked to?

Comment: It behaves the exact same way, remove DELETE to see that.  I'm guessing it is a Win10 specific issue, somebody ought to talk to MSFT about it.  I'll volunteer you.

Comment: @HansPassant I've tried it now under Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012 as well, and the behaviour is the same as on Windows 10. Unfortunately, I still fail to see the similarity to the linked post on deleting files by disk id. When I remove the `DELETE` flag, I get an access denied error, whereas the problem in the linked question is (as far as I understand it) that `OpenFileByDiskId` seems to ignore the `DELETE` flag, such that the resulting handle is not fit to use with `SetFileInformationByHandle` to *delete* the file.

Comment: @Gerardo I'll first have to test it on several operating systems. Then I'll upvote. Is there any need to hurry accepting your answer? My plan was to wait with accepting an answer and giving the bounty until the end of the bounty period.

Answer (score 5):

I change a couple of thinks:

1) i dont use root handle (i set it to NULL)

2) i change your FILE_RENAME_INFO memory allocation code

NOTE: checked in windows 8, moving file in the same volume (disk)

```
auto const& filepath = L"C:\\remove_tests\\file.txt";
auto const& destpath = L"C:\\remove_tests\\other.txt";
// unclear if that's the "root directory"
auto const& rootdir = L"C:\\remove_tests";

// handles will be leaked but that should be irrelevant here
auto const f_handle = CreateFile(filepath,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE | DELETE,
      0,
    NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);

if (f_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    auto const err = GetLastError();
    std::cerr << "failed to create test file: " << err;
    return err;
}

/*auto const parent_dir_handle = CreateFile(rootdir,
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE | DELETE,
      FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
    NULL);

if (parent_dir_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    auto const err = GetLastError();
    std::cerr << "failed to get handle to parent directory: " << err;
    return err;
}*/

 auto const destpath_bytes_withOUT_null = _tcslen(destpath);
// unclear if we need to subtract the one wchar_t of FileNameLength:
auto const struct_size = sizeof(FILE_RENAME_INFO) + (destpath_bytes_withOUT_null + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR);
FILE_RENAME_INFO* fri = (FILE_RENAME_INFO*)new BYTE[struct_size];

fri->ReplaceIfExists =  TRUE; // as described by Niall Douglas
fri->RootDirectory = NULL;//parent_dir_handle;
// with or without null terminator?
fri->FileNameLength = destpath_bytes_withOUT_null;// No include null
 _tcscpy_s(fri->FileName, destpath_bytes_withOUT_null + 1, destpath);

BOOL res = SetFileInformationByHandle(f_handle, FileRenameInfo,
                                      fri, struct_size);

 delete fri;
if (!res)
{
    auto const err = GetLastError();
    std::cerr << "failed to rename file: " << err;
    return err;
}
else
    std::cout << "success";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've checked it now under Windows 10 and it works; tests on other operating systems will have to wait until Monday. I guess **not** using the root handle would be the last thing that I tried... In my original source code, only removing the root handle is also sufficient to make it work. The `FileNameLength` seems to be ignored (can also be set to 0). Only the `DELETE` right appears to be required for `f_handle`.

Comment: Yes, DELETE is only flag required when you create file handle, you could see it at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I cannt find any reason why RootDirectory must be NULL, but i guess: it works in kernel mode, or because FILE_RENAME_INFO is shared for SetFileInformationByHandle, NtSetInformationFile & ZwSetInformationFile, maybe it has some sense use  RootDirectory != NULL in other functions

Comment: Wow, it says why it needs `RootDirectory == NULL` in the description you've linked. I did not see that because I was navigating from `SetFileInformationByHandle`, where you end up at the [FILE_RENAME_INFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure instead of the [FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure you've linked to. Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, but if you try to use **RootDirectory != NULL** it fails, even when manual says it must work

Comment: Let me explain you very carefully my comments: if you walk inside SetFileInformationByHandle in a dissamsembly window, you find that functions calls NtSetInformationFile, if you search a little this last function uses FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION but its only a synonymous for FILE_RENAME_INFO, in fact SetFileInformationByHandle just pass this struct directly with any conversion to NtSetInformationFile. BECAUSE THAT you could use help related to FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION safely in order to understand FILE_RENAME_INFO.

Comment: Non-null `RootDirectory` works just fine for relative/race free renames, but no `HANDLE` anywhere in the system can be open on that directory with the `DELETE` permission held. Yes, this sucks. But it is what it is.

Comment: On my computer (Win10 21H1) it only works with an *absolute* file name and RootDirectory == NULL. Using a relative file name doesn't work here with RootDirectory == NULL.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for `SetFileInformationByHandle` with `FileRenameInfo` and `FILE_RENAME_INFO` contains some errors.
`FILE_RENAME_INFO.FileNameLength` must be set to the number of characters copied to `FILE_RENAME_INFO.FileName` excluding the terminating zero, and `FILE_RENAME_INFO.RootDirectory` must be null, even if moving the file from one directory to another.

```
#include <sdkddkver.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv [] )
{
    wchar_t* filename = L"C:\\remove_tests\\file.txt";
    wchar_t* destFilename = L"C:\\remove_tests2\\other.txt";

    // handles will be leaked but that should be irrelevant here
    auto fileHandle = CreateFile( filename,
                                  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE | DELETE,
                                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                                      NULL,
                                      OPEN_EXISTING,
                                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                      NULL );

    if ( fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        auto const err = GetLastError( );
        std::cerr << "failed to create test file: " << err;
        return err;
    }

    auto destFilenameLength = wcslen( destFilename );

    auto bufferSize = sizeof( FILE_RENAME_INFO ) + ( destFilenameLength*sizeof( wchar_t ));
    auto buffer = _alloca( bufferSize );
    memset( buffer, 0, bufferSize );

    auto const fri = reinterpret_cast<FILE_RENAME_INFO*>( buffer );
    fri->ReplaceIfExists = TRUE;

    fri->FileNameLength = destFilenameLength;
    wmemcpy( fri->FileName, destFilename, destFilenameLength );

    BOOL res = SetFileInformationByHandle( fileHandle, FileRenameInfo, fri, bufferSize );
    if ( !res )
    {
        auto const err = GetLastError( );
        std::cerr << "failed to rename file: " << err;
        return err;
    }
    else
        std::cout << "success";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How did you determine that the documentation contains errors? By experiment, or do you have another source?

Comment: [At another site](http://www.codeproject.com/Members/Espen-Harlinn) I have a slightly different ranking - and I think you'll find that I have some experience related to the ins and outs of the Windows API.
It is rather obvious that something isn’t quite right with regards to the documentation for using SetFileInformationByHandle and FILE_RENAME_INFO. The FileName member of FILE_RENAME_INFO is Unicode based, so it was kind of natural to try out the number of Unicode characters.

Comment: Well from my tests, it seems that the `FileNameLength` member is ignored entirely, the `RootDirectory` handle seems to be the culprit. I was mainly wondering because I'd appreciate learning about alternative sources of information about the Windows API, MSDN sometimes not being enough (as it is here). This being your first answer on StackOverflow, and one hour after Gerardo's answer (containing essentially the same hints) also made me a bit suspicious, I have to admit :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit off the main question, but why don't you try **C++17** `filesystem` library as a standard portable way?
You can simply use **[`std::filesystem::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename)**, supported by [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem-functions?view=msvc-170#rename) too. I didn't provide an example, because it'd be essentially a copy of the **cppreference** example in the first link above. It has a much simpler and straightforward API.

Comment: I'm not sure if that was available for me in 2016 when I asked this question, and it also suffers from the issue that you have to construct the path in a first step, and then perform the renaming in a second step. Between these steps, the filesystem can change (hence "filesystem races").

Comment: It's C++17 stuff, thus 2018 is most likely the earliest time to be able to **portably** use it. `std::path` is just a string of characters with convenience functions. It doesn't access file system for creating a hypothetical path. File system is only accessed when `rename` or any actual filesystem manipulator functions are used. So, I don't see what problem you are referring to. If there are any recorded defect report or documents on the issue, I`d be curious to read. The underlying implementation needs only one kernel call.

Comment: I'd recommend watching the talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhRWMGBjlO8 if you haven't done so already. The issue is that you pass a path as a string to the kernel, and the kernel has to resolve this to an actual file. If you want to ensure that a particular file is deleted, you have to pass the kernel a _handle_ to that file. If you pass a string path instead, you can't ensure that the kernel will operate on the file you had in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but he doesn't delve that much into windows. He just mentions that delete should be handled in terms of rename. So, if there's anything about `std:: filesystem::rename` or its prototype in BOOST, I'd be to know. AFIO that he proposed is not in neither in BOOST, nor anywhere near std. So the guy is either totally inactive now, or very wrong. C++20 coroutines is a mess and anything relying on this particular implementation IMHO will fail terribly. Anyhow, I need an example case for the kind of failure you want to prevent.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with coroutines... Assuming MSVC implemented the "atomic" part of `rename` correctly, they're probably using `SetFileInformationByHandle` under the hood. I don't quite remember what I was trying to do seven years ago, but today I would be concerned about: what do other threads, processes see when they access the old/new path (atomicity)? can renaming fail if other threads operate on either the old/new path (and what's the result then)? if I already have a file handle, how can I move that file via handle (to prevent TOCTOU issues)?